# reuse of TMemoryStream delphi/c++ builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

How to re-use correctly a TMemoryStream in a cycle. For example I have a timer and I'm downloading something from internet directly in a TMemoryStream object.

this object is declared as global variable:

```
TMemoryStream *ms;
```

then I use it in a timer function:

```
ms = new TMemoryStream;

.... other operations with ms ....
```

then I use it in other function where i do not need this stream at the end and want to empty it, and i do:

```
delete ms;
```

and then again is called same timer function, and it does the same cycle allocating and deallocating. It is correctly by this way ?

or I should ms->Clear() or ms->Free() in my last function where stream is no more need ?

I'm interested in how to reuse same global variable to read the stream (allocate) and empty the stream (deallocate).

Comment: I would recommend not to try and re-use it in this case. Declare and create a different instance each time.

Comment: I need it to be global accessible, i need to use the stream in other function which i cannot pass it as parameter

Comment: Well that's dangerous re-creating the same variable from within a timer - how often does this timer tick? Because it's possible for a timer's execution to overlap.

Comment: How is this Q related to Delphi?

Comment: @Jerry overlap with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is not dangerous or a mistake to instantiate and free an object in a timer, because timer calls have no overlap while thread calls may have. As Remy said, it is better to use only **Clear()** in timer and at end delete stream inside OnDestroy or form destructor (**__fastcall** ~TForm1()).

Answer (score 0):

`Free()` is Delphi's equivilent to C++'s `delete` - the object gets destroyed.  If you just want to reuse the same object but empty out its contents each time, use `Clear()`.  Just remember that at some point, you will need to call `delete` to free the object when you are not going to use it anymore.